# Global Array not found when adding script dynamically in IE9

Tags: javascript, dynamic, cross-browser, load, internet-explorer-9

I have two JavaScript files: "One" and "Two". The "One" file is adding the "Two" dynamically as follows:

```
scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
scriptNode.type = 'text/javascript'
scriptNode.src = '/JavaScript/Two.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptNode);
```

Then, after the "Two" file is loaded, the "One" file is using its functions. 
The situation is something like this:

1. The "One" file loads the "Two" file.
2. In the "Two" file a global array is declared, when it is loaded.
3. In the "One" file function from the "Two" file is called to populated the global array.

The functions in the "Two" file that populates the global array is like this:

```
GlobalArray=new Array();

function Init(name){
    this.name=name;
}

function PopulateGlobalArray(name){
    var temp=new Init(name);
    GlobalArray.push(temp);

    console.log(GlobalArray.length); // returns "1"
    OtherStuff();
}

function OtherStuff(){
    console.log(GlobalArray.length); // returns "0" only in IE9
}
```

In the "One" file I am calling PopulateGlobalArray() function.

In every browser (Opera,Firefox,Ghrome,IE7,IE8,IE10) in `OtherStuff()` the `console.log()` returns `1`.
In IE9, it returns `0` - the array is just empty.

It took me a lot of time, but finally I have found that if I am including the "Two" file in the HTML as

```
<script src="/JavaScript/Two.js"></script>
```

or not loading it with JavaScript, it is working on IE9, too.

My question is has anyone a clue why this is happening?

EDIT: I am pretty sure this is connected with the DOCTYPE. I am using Strict Doctype, but Browse Mode:IE9 with Dicument Mode: Quirks does not cause the error.

Comment: How about adding GlobalArray to the window object. I.e. window.GlobalArray = new Array(). You might just need to preceed it with the var keyword though.

Comment: I have try using 'var' before. window.GlobalArray = new Array(); changes nothings, and var window.GlobalArray = new Array(); gives me error "Expected ';' "